# How do you tell using PHP whether a webpage is using iframes?

Tags: php

If i enter a site name in the text input,i want to know just one thing whether iframes has been used in a website or not. If yes it should return iframes found, otherwise iframes not found.

Comment: do you have control over the code of the website you want to check?

Comment: i am not getting the basic idea how to know that...

Comment: @dragonjet:if i enter a site in a text input i should know whether the site is using iframes or not....

Answer (score 2):

Seems easy enough:

```
 <form method="post">
   <input type="text" name="url" value="">
   <input type="submit">
 </form>
    <?php 


function usingIframes($url){
      $html = file_get_contents($url);
      $d = new DOMDocument();
      $d->loadHTML("$html");
      $iframe = $d->getElementByTagName('iframe'); 
      return ($iframe->length>0);
    }

    if($_POST) 
       if(usingIframes($_POST['url'])) 
              echo "Using Iframes"; 
          else 
             echo "No frames";
```

Will return true if the url you've supplied has the iframe tag in it. False if not.

Comment: I think he's trying to figure out if a page on a site is being included without consent via iframe on some other site. Just a hunch. Probably not worth the trouble to help though, I don't think he cares to make an effort at doing anything on his own :)

Comment: it is showing error in this line what may be the problem-->$iframe = $d->getElementByTagName('iframe');

Comment: am new to the php...the above code is not working can any body help me regarding this plz..

Answer (score 0):

To do it with PHP you'll need to put something in the frame URL to let PHP know, like ?iframe-true. Assuming you're trying to make sure a site isn't included in an iframe without permission, you can do it by putting some Javascript in the page. Tons of ways to do it: http://www.google.com/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=javascript+break+out+of+iframe

Comment: hi David ,can u guide me with the code in php script i am not able to get it

Answer (score 0):

Just search the content of the page for `<IFRAME>`

Comment: @deceze-i have done like that but its not showing the correct result here is the code if there are any corrections plz rectify it

Comment: <?php
$url = 'http://www.example.com';
$meta = '<IFRAME>';
$contents = file_get_contents($url);
if(strpos($contents, $meta)!== false) {
echo 'found';
} else {
echo 'not found';
} 
?>

Comment: if i enter the site url in the input text it should display all the linksin that particular website i have done it using strpos but not getting 
here is the code can any bodu rectify it

$url = 'http://www.example.com';
$meta = '"/\<a href ([a-zA-Z]|[\=\"])+ \>|\<\/a\>/";';
$contents = file_get_contents($url);
if(strpos($contents, $meta)!== false) {
echo 'found';
} else {
echo 'not found';
} 
?>
echo $meta;